# Java Protobuf Compiler: public fields

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

When using the java compiler for protobuf all the fields in the `.proto` file get generated as `private` with getters and setters.
Is it possible to generate public accessible fields in the Java class so that for a proto like the following

```
message MyModel {
   string my_field = 1;
}
```

I can reference to its fields in java in the following way

```
MyModel.myField;
```

instead of what the compiler currently gives me which is

```
MyModel.getMyField();
```

Comment: what do you need that for?

Comment: I am using jython to interact with this Java code from python and I'd like to use a syntax without getters

Comment: (just in case, you could also generate the protobuf classes in python, but I assume you already know that). I'm not aware of such options in protoc.